# What is the best way to get all elements in a hashmap?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I know I can use `.values()` and `.keyset()` to get the respective keys/values on their own (from a hashmap). I am trying to get them together and return that in a get method.

Could I use `entryset()` to get an entry, but do it in a loop to produce an array list of entryset's and then return that? Not sure if that is the best way though. Any advice?

Comment: can't get you ...can you write some code for better explaination

Comment: entrySet() will give you a set containing all the entries, not a single one.

Comment: `entrySet().toArray` looks good to me

Answer (score 5):

The [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29) method already returns a collection of all of the entries (key/value pairs) in the map, not just a single entry.  I think you want to just call this once and use the set that it returns instead of calling it in a loop and populating a list.

Answer (score 2):

entrySet() returns a Set of all entries of HashMap.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Set;

public class HashMapEntrySet {

public static void main(String[] arr) {

/* Create object of HashMap */

HashMap<Integer, String> obHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

/* Strore value in HashMap */

obHashMap.put(new Integer(1), "AAA");

obHashMap.put(new Integer(2), "BBB");

obHashMap.put(new Integer(3), "CCC");

obHashMap.put(new Integer(4), "DDD");

obHashMap.put(new Integer(5), "EEE");

/* Create a set of keys of hashmap */

Set obEntrySet = obHashMap.entrySet();

System.out.println("Set of entries : " + obEntrySet); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `entrySet()` on the `Map` to get a set of ALL entries in the `Map`. You can either return the whole set or iterate over it if additional manipulations need to be made.